Is $\omega_1$ Meta-Lindelöf?
A space is meta-Lindelöf provided every open cover of $X$ has a point-countable open refinement. (A collection $\mathscr V$ of subsets of $X$ is point-countable if each point $x\in X$ belongs to at most countably many elements of $\mathscr V$.)
It's noted in Steen and Seebach's Counterexamples in Topology that the ordinal $\omega_1$ with its order topology is not metacompact (every open cover of $X$ has a point-finite open refinement). Does it in fact violate meta-Lindelöf?
An answer would resolve this currently open question from $\pi$-Base: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000035/properties/P000083.

Alternatively, meta-Lindelöf countably compact spaces are compact, see Handbook of set-theoretic topology, chapter 9, 9.2 and 4.1.

It does fail to be meta-Lindelöf.
Consider the open cover $\mathcal U=\{\{0\}\}\cup\{(0,\alpha]:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ and a refinement $\mathcal V$. For each $\alpha<\omega_1$ there is some $f(\alpha)<\alpha$ with $(f(\alpha),\alpha]$ contained in some open set in $\mathcal V$. By the Pressing-Down lemma there is some $\beta<\omega_1$ with $f(\alpha)=\beta$ for $\omega_1$-many $\alpha<\omega_1$. It follows that $\beta+1$ is contained in uncountably-many sets from $\mathcal V$, showing there is no point-countable refinement of $\mathcal U$.
